# ASP.NET windows authentication and impersionation

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm trying to impersonate user authenticated through windows authentication.
So I enabled on IIS (version 7.5) both ASP.NET Impersonation and Windows authentication. If I use impersonation to a specific user it works correctly

```
<identity impersonate="true" password="mypa$$" userName="MYDOMAIN\myUser" />
```

If I don't specify user, in order to impersonate windows authenticated user, I get an error (HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error. Logon Method: Not yet determined, Logon User: Not yet determined)

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to add extra code line in web.config to specify that I want to impersonate the windows authenticated user?

EDIT: I solved by adding this line, even if I didn't really understand what it means

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

Comment: Can you please check if you have enabled windows authentication and disabled anonymous authentication?

Comment: Yes, windows authentication is enabled and anonymous authentication is disabled

Comment: Can you please using basic authentication instead of windows? For some reason, the asp.net not detecting the windows logged in user.

Comment: That is not a solution. First user is prompted for credential, and I don't want this. Second, it doesn't work anyway, because impersonation doesn't take place